# Needing to get json data back without the parent UID attached

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, postman, amcharts

We are using AmCharts and it has an option that reads external JSON, but we are using firebase as our database and everything in our node has a parent UID.

chart.dataSource.url = "OurUrlGoesHere.json"

and when I put a get request in postman Im getting all the data back I need but it has parent tags, like so

```
    "-MKqgY_L2QNxoF2Ks7Sr": {
        "eventName": "Test Event",
        "eventPrice": 4377
    },
```

but I need the data like this

```
{
        "eventName": "Test Event",
        "eventPrice": 4377
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `parseended` event to modify your data:

```
chart.dataSource.events.on("parseended", function(ev) {
  var data = ev.target.data;
  if (!!data) {
    data = Object.values(data);
  }
});
```

We also made use of the Object.values() method to get the values only, without the keys. This converts the response from an object full of objects to an array full of objects.

**Documentation**

- amCharts Loading External Data/Handling Events - https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/data/loading-external-data#Handling_events
- Object.values at MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values